# Forwarding a entire Outlook inbox to a different account?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

We have a senior employee who is leaving.  My boss showed me what our previous IT employee set up for him, it looked like folders on his Outlook, and underneath was the full inbox/draft/spam etc of that person's outlook.

Now they want the same thing for this employee who is leaving.  We are setup with an active directory if that matters.  How can I achieve this for leaving employees email to forward everything to my bosses email (inside of a folder or folder like object)?

I'm wondering and thinking too perhaps my boss was just granted full permissions to view these mailboxes - if that's the case and the easy way to do things, how can I set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [create a shared mailbox](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/Office-365-Course/Shared-Mailbox.htm) with the same address, and add it to your boss' Outlook client. This will allow you to deactivate the (soon to be) former employee's account after they leave, but not give your boss access to historical contents of their mailbox.

Or, you could [add delegate permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user?view=o365-worldwide) for your boss to the user's mailbox, and then [add it to your boss'](https://www.ucc.ie/en/it/services/office365/howto/openmailbox/) Outlook client. This will give your box access to the historical contents of the mailbox, but you will need to keep the account active to keep receiving emails at that address.

Comment: The plan now is to keep the email active as we are expecting our customers to continue emailing this employee for at least the next few months from people who are unaware he is leaving so we do want to get those emails so my boss can respond to them.  I am going to try the delegate permissions way.

Comment: Great! Please mark this answer as correct if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply convert that mailbox to a shared mailbox, and granting your boss full access permission. If you are using on-prem Exchange server, refer to the method here:[Convert User Mailbox to Shared Mailbox](https://www.mustbegeek.com/convert-user-mailbox-to-shared-mailbox/). If O365:[Convert a user mailbox to a shared mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/convert-user-mailbox-to-shared-mailbox?view=o365-worldwide)

And the command for full access:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity <MailboxIdentity> -User <DelegateIdentity> -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

In addition, from outlook side, you could consider exporting the folder file you need to a .pst file and import them to your boss's outlook. [Import and export Outlook email, contacts, and calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-and-export-outlook-email-contacts-and-calendar-92577192-3881-4502-b79d-c3bbada6c8ef)